# How do I add "Enter" to a Tiny MCE custom shortcut key combo?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

So basically for my TinyMCe editor I want to add a shortcut like ctrl+Enter which I can then trigger some behaviour.

I found the custom shortcut docs:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.shortcuts/
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#addshortcut

But couldn't find any reference of how I can check for an "Enter" key with a "ctrl" key. All the examples are for combinations like "ctrl+a", "meta+a" etc.

Anyone know how to do a "ctrl+Enter" combo?

I'm currently using v5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the numeric key code (`13`) combined with the meta key name (`ctrl`) like this:

```
editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+13', 'Test CTRL ENTER', function() {
    alert('CTRL ENTER!');
    // do whatever you need to do here!
});
```